# Getting github stargazer count

Tags: github-api

I've been using the `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stargazers` endpoint, but I've noticed that it only provides 30 stargazers, which isn't enough for my purposes now. I've switched to the search API, `GET /search/repositories?q=:repo` (`items[0].stargazers_count`), but what if someone creates 20 repos with the same name? I'd have to make more than one request. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/repos/:owner/:repo/stargazers` endpoint is paginated. You can get all of the stargazers from that endpoint quickly and easily. For example, if you were to use github3.py it would be 3 lines:

```
import github3

repo = github3.repository(':owner', ':repo')
stargazers = list(repo.stargazers())
```

This however cannot be done in a single request (which is why it's paginated).

Using the search API is probably the cheapest, but your concern about a single person having 20 repositories with the same name is not sensible. A single user can only have one repository with a specific name. That, however, shouldn't be considered a guarantee that there won't be more than one result so you should probably use a different query string, e.g.,

```
import github3

github3.search_repositories('repo:owner/repo_name')
```

Which should translate roughly to

```
GET /search/repositories?q=repo%3Aowner%2Frepo_name
```

Comment: Yes, it does. I hadn't noticed the existence of the `repo:owner/repo_name` query, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As 2020 from [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Repository.html#get-count-of-stars)

`pip3 install PyGithub`

```py
from github import Github
g = Github()
repo = g.get_repo("PyGithub/PyGithub")
repo.stargazers_count
```